# CSS reordering and repositioning of HTML elements

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement to change a certain menu for the mobile version. The desktop version has six menu items dully positioned in one row like:

```
one two three four five six.
```

Now, for the mobile version the layout should be:

```
one five six
two
three
four
```

I tried to apply `display: flex;` to the `ul` element of the menu and then applied order to the menu items. However, it seems I can't get through because I couldn't apply `display: block;`to the `il` items two, three and four.

I tried another way applying `display: box;`. Let me show this part that *almost* gives me a solution:

```css
#menu {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: box;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -moz-box-orient: vertical;
 box-orient: vertical;
}

ul { list-style: none; }
 
#menu-1 {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
 box-ordinal-group: 1;
}
 
#menu-2 {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4;
 box-ordinal-group: 4;
}
 
#menu-3 {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 5;
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: 5;
 box-ordinal-group: 5;
}
 
#menu-4 {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 6;
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: 6;
 box-ordinal-group: 6;
}
 
#menu-5 {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
 box-ordinal-group: 2;
}
 
#menu-5 {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
 box-ordinal-group: 3;
}

#menu-1, #menu-5, #menu-6 {
 color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
}

#menu-2, #menu-3, #menu-4 { 
 color: red;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu-container">
   <ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu-1">one</li>
    <li id="menu-2">two</li>
    <li id="menu-3">three</li>
    <li id="menu-4">four</li>
    <li id="menu-5">five</li>
    <li id="menu-6">six</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Life would be much more wonderful if I could get the `one` item in the same row as items `five` and `six`. I tried floats but that way the item `one` just disappears. So I am asking you this: "Is there a way to join all three elements in one row?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/igorbeuermann/ufko4cvs/16/)

Comment: I think you want `<li>` not `<il>` (for starters).

Comment: You think right but that doesn't help much.

Comment: But thank you anyway - I changed tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter between flexbox and CSS grid

Flexbox doesn't allow us to place items in specific places, but CSS grid does.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* mobile media */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    display: inline-grid;
  }
  li:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
  li:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 4;
  }
  li:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  li:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>
```

---

Flexbox hack with pseudo-element if you don't mind setting a fixed height on the parent.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* mobile media */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 160px;
  }
  ul:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
  }
  li:nth-child(6) {
    order: 7
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That made my day! Thank you, @zohir-salak! I did vote up but you cannot see it at your answer because of my bad reputation ...

Comment: @IgorBeuermann you can also simplify like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4qa98L1t/